# Force update of child view controller's safeAreaInsets

Tags: ios, autolayout, safearealayoutguide

I have a `rootViewController` that has a child view controller (`fullScreenViewController`) whose view, from time to time, is displayed *above* the view (but as a subview) of the `rootViewController`, taking up the full screen.

i.e. 
`rootViewController.addChildViewController( fullScreenViewController )`
`rootViewController.view.addSubview( fullScreenViewController.view )`

This "full screen presentation" is done with constraints updates, *not* by using `present()` (There's good reason for this).

When I first initialize `fullScreenViewController` and add it as a child view controller of `rootViewController`, then update the constraints so that it is on screen, the `safeAreaInsets` are all set properly.

However, when, later on, my `rootViewController` actually does `present()` a modal VC, and that VC is `dismiss()`ed, the `safeAreaInsets` on the `fullScreenViewController` are no longer correct, and the content in the `fullScreenViewController` slides up on top of the status bar.

How can I force the `safeAreaInsets` on `fullScreenViewController` to be recalculated properly, so that they match the `rootViewController` the way they do after setup?

According to the documentation, the `rootViewController` should be setting the  safeAreaInsets properly on all of its `childViewController`s, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

[image: Safe Area Insets Correct]

[image: Safe Area Insets Incorrect]

Comment: I have the exact same issue, displaying a modal above the container view controller will mess the child's safe area insets. Where you able to find the reason for this or a fix?

Answer (score 5):

I had the exact same issue with a child view controller's `safeAreaInsets` not being properly refreshed after a presentation changed the safe area.

I found that the issue was resolved by making the child's view a direct subview of the parent's view, when before it was a subview of a subview. I guess UIKit code is happier when child VC's views are direct subviews of parent's.

If you can refactor your view hierarchy to this configuration (if not already the case) this might do it.

Comment: I ended up refactoring most of my view hierarchy, and something in there fixed it for me. I'll have to play with your solution to see if that is the particular issue I'm having. Seems promising though; glad you got it fixed!

Comment: Does not work in my case.